# ESD control to protect personnel inside container van

Tags: esd

we are doing a simulator project inside a 30-foot container van. All equipment will be grounded to a central earthing point. Each grounding connection should be less than 2ohms.

Van will be used on land and on ships.

Operators inside van will be trained according to simulation requirement (eg bus driving, tank operation, aircraft combat etc).

What ESD control can we put in place to protect personnel from ESD shocks/zaps? we don't want them wearing wrist straps due to nature of simulation training.

Comment: Heel straps and ground the floor? But that means everyone has to put something onto their foot. Also ESD measures do not protect the people, they protect the parts and grounding the person can make things more dangerous for the person. You will have to be clear what it is you want to do exactly

Comment: By the way, heel straps also have to eventually make contact with bare skin somewhere on your leg as well.

Comment: all equipment will be grounded with a grounding strap. straps will be connected to each chassis or housing and then other end to common ground bus or frame. grounding floor means floor should have a resistance to grounding point (earthing point) of between 50kohms to 1Meg.

Comment: esd control is avoid zapping personnel inside van. i guess esd shoes will be required.

Comment: What you said still doesn't make sense. ESD control is to avoid personnel zapping equipment inside the van. It does NOT protect against equipment zapping people. Are you trying to protect the equipment from the people? Or the people from the equipment? Are you afraid of people damaging the equipment? Or are you afraid of the equipment hurting people?

Comment: people from equipment.

Comment: If you are wanting to protect people from being hurt by the equipment then those aren't ESD measures. Please correct your post. You do not want wrist straps or heel straps as these are conductive connections between the equipment and people. But you do want equipment casings to be grounded, as well as exposed metal surfaces (except maybe the floor). The floor should probably be insulated.

Comment: wrist straps or heel straps have a minimum 1Meg resistor in them.

Comment: That 1MOhm resistor is there *precisely* because it is *more* hazardous while wearing an ESD strap. Wearing a 1MOhm ESD strap makes it safer than wearing a  0Ohm ESD strap, but it doesn't make it safer than not wearing one. That's like saying it's safer to stand on a a roof than the ground because you have a harness when you're on the roof. It's clearly more dangerous on the roof than the ground even if you have a safety harness.

Comment: i guess best solution is a good ESD flooring as explained here: https://kb.staticworx.com/selecting-specifying-esd-floor/choosing-esd-flooring-mission-critical-spaces/

Comment: You're still missing the point. If you want to protect personnel from being hurt by the equipment, ESD is NOT THE GOAL. Some practices might overlap (like grounding equipment enclosures), but any that do not will just make things more dangerous for the personnel. You're better off insulating the floor entirely.

Comment: yes, ESD floors have resistance of between 1Meg and 10Meg. will contact various esd floor manufacturers for advice. thanks!

Comment: You're not getting it. Why pay money for ESD flooring to get 1MegOhm or 10MegOhms when it is LESS safe than cheaper, regular, insulating rubber flooring with more Megaohms? What you need is NOT ESD protection. You need the OPPOSITE if it is the personnel you want to protect. Adding ESD protection makes things LESS safe.

Comment: with rubber flooring, static buildup increases with personnel movement inside. how do you dissipate this charge if floor is insulated? use of wrist straps/heels are not recommended due to nature of training activities inside the van. i think you're not getting ESD control concept.

Comment: The problem here is you keep saying two different things. In the title you say you want ESD protection. In the post you say you want to protect personnel from shocks. These are two different things. I asked you in the comments which was it you actually wanted and you answered you wanted to protect personnel from shocks, but just now you are talking about ESD protection again. Which is it that you want? You keep jumping back and forth. You're the one who doesn't seem to be understanding what it is you are asking for. Protecting personnel from shocks is NOT ESD control. Which do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments I suspect the correct question is: "*how to protect personnel operating mobile equipment from shocks*"

To which the answer is, with ground and residual current protection.
You attach a ground lead to the chassis of the container, and this lead goes to a ground rod. A big spike in the ground.
Then you attach one lead of the power supply, battery/generator to the chassis. This is neutral. And you wire up a switchboard of RCD breaker (GFCI) that then trips at soon as there is too much leakage. As in someone is touching the live wire.

Buy the right kind of RCD, for DC they are more complicated.

On mobile generators you sometimes have multiple ground rods with a protection device to ensure ground impendance is correct before enabling the power supply.

Obviously when using an external mobile generator or mains you can't just tie one lead to ground. Those plugs will already offer you a ground and neutral wire since they did probably that for you already depending on local electrical standards.

> eg bus driving, tank operation, aircraft combat etc

This suggests you're making a military mobile command centre, for which I'm sure there are tons of guidelines and regulations regarding electrical safety.

Comment: Safety first. I think you got it right in spite of long comments.+1

Comment: thank you. so proper grounding with RCD/GFCI should address ESD requirements.

Comment: @ArielNarboada ESD is something completely different that requires much more invasive and trourough precautions. Eg: shoes, clothes, chairs, tables, humidity control and training.